# restoring wim files from external drive to hard drive on computer

Tags: windows, restore, wim

how do I restore wim files to my hard drive?  I saved filed after computer crashed, to an external drive.  Now I need to restore those files to my hard drive.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISM or ImageX to apply a WIM to a partition:

```
Dism /apply-image /imagefile:N:\Images\my-windows-partition.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\
```

**Source:**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824910.aspx